# How to round trip ruamel.yaml strings like "on"

Tags: ruamel.yaml

When using [ruamel.yaml](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/overview) to round-trip some YAML I see the following issue. Given this input:

```
root:
  matchers:
    - select: "response.body#state"
      test: all
      expected: "on"
```

I see this output:

```
root:
  matchers:
    - select: response.body#state
      test: all
      expected: on
```

Note that in YAML, `on` parses as a boolean `true` value while `off` parses as `false`.

The following code is used to read/write:

```
# Use the default (round-trip) settings.
yaml = YAML()

if args.source == '-':
    src = sys.stdin
else:
    src = open(args.source)

doc = yaml.load(src)
process(args.tag, set(args.keep.split(',')), doc)

if args.destination == '-':
    dest = sys.stdout
else:
    dest = open(args.destination, 'w')

yaml.dump(doc, dest)
```

The `process` function is not modifying values. It only removes things with a special tag in the input after crawling the structure.

How can I get the output to be a string rather than a boolean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write that:

> Note that in YAML, `on` parses as a boolean `true` value while `off` parses as `false`.

That statement is not true (or better:
has not been true for ten years). If you have an unquoted `on` in your
YAML, like in your output, that is obviously not the case when using ruamel.yaml:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
root:
  matchers:
    - select: response.body#state
      test: all
      expected: on
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
expected = data['root']['matchers'][0]['expected']
print(type(expected), repr(expected))
```

which gives:

```
<class 'str'> 'on'
```

This is because in the YAML 1.2 spec `on`/`off`/`yes`/`no` are no
longer mentioned as having the same meaning as `true`
resp. `false`. They *are* mentioned in the YAML 1.1 spec, but that was
superseded in 2009. Unfortunately there are YAML libraries out in the
wild, that have not been updated since then.

What is actually happening is that the suprefluous quotes in your
input are automatically discarded by the round-trip process. You can
also see that happen for the value `"response.body#state"`. Although
there the character that starts comments (`#`) is included, to
actually start a comment that character has to be proceded by
white-space, and since it is isn't, the quotes are not necessary.

**So your output is fine**, but if you are in the unfortunate
situation where you have to deal with other programs relying on
outdated YAML 1.1, then you can e.g. specify that you want to preserve
your quotes on round-trip:

```
yaml_str = """\
root:
  matchers:
    - select: "response.body#state"
      test: all
      expected: "on"
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

as this gives your exact input:

```
root:
  matchers:
    - select: "response.body#state"
      test: all
      expected: "on"
```

However maybe the better option would be that you actually specify that your
YAML is and has to conforming to the YAML 1.1 specification by making
your intensions, and the output document, *explicit*:

```
yaml_str = """\
root:
  matchers:
    - select: response.body#state
      test: all
      expected: on
"""

yaml_in = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml_out = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml_out.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml_out.version = (1, 1)
data = yaml_in.load(yaml_str)
yaml_out.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Notice that the "unquoted" YAML 1.2 input, gives output where `on` is quoted:

```
%YAML 1.1
---
root:
  matchers:
    - select: response.body#state
      test: all
      expected: 'on'
```

Comment: Fascinating! Thank you for the thorough response. I found that many tools, including things like Kubernetes and OpenAPI parsers, don't support YAML 1.2 booleans properly. See for example https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/214.

I like your example to preserve quotes. This allows people to format their document however the downstream tool needs, and my processor will leave their formatting as-is. This should result in the least surprises for users. Thanks for the great library!